# Installing bootstrap in rails - removing current assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I see https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails how I can add bootstrap to a completely new application, using `rails generate scaffold Product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets`.

My question is: how do I delete the current assets (e.g. stylesheets) from an existing application so I can install bootstrap and not have any conflicts?

PS this command seems to be for a scaffold - does it create a layout for the entire application?

Comment: Your application uses `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as a default layout for the whole app. That's a Rails convention whether you use scaffolds or not.

Comment: Okay thanks; how do I delete it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to use bootstrap, *instead* of the default layout

Comment: You need both. Perhaps you're being put off by the word 'layout', but in Rails that doesn't mean a default design or anything like that. It's just a barebones HTML file. Since Bootstrap is only CSS, you need the HTML to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SASS, there is a gem https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass that you could use instead of doing what you are trying now. As long as you have

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

in a stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets ending with extension .css.scss (e.g. example.css.scss)

Comment: And this works even after I already have stylesheets? Or do I still have to delete them? And how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: I'm not a pro at this. but for me, the other stylesheets within the stylesheets folder over write or add on to the existing bootstrap styles. why not give it a try and remove it if it doesn't work for you?

Comment: also, for your info, scss(http://sass-lang.com/) stands for sassy css. sass allows you to nest css attributes which is pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet are stored under `app/assets/stylesheets` and listed individually in a manifest file, which by default is `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`.

Do not delete the manifest file. Open it, go through every item listed and delete them one by one -- both the manifest entry and the actual files. Pay attention to the `require_tree` and `require_directory` directives since they include entire directories.

Comment: Okay thanks; so do I need to delete these entire directories?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what you need to delete without looking at your file. As long as you don't delete the manifest itself, you shouldn't run into any errors. Do you have a lot of previously existing stylesheets?

Comment: Also, I agree with @stonefruit's answer. That gem `bootstrap-sass` is indeed nice.